# hyperref: Include 'sec.', 'tab.' etc. in links to chapters, tables etc

Tags: hyperref, labels

How can I include variables in a `\ref` command? Specifically, I'd like my custom command

```
\newcommand{\See}[1]{\ref{#1}, pg. \pageref{#1}}
```

to be able to distinguish between different kinds of things it's referencing.

So:
When I write `\See{tab:interesting table}`, it outputs something like '3.6, pg. 31', but I want it to output something like 'tab. 3.6, pg. 31'.
When I write `\See{sec:interesting section}`, it outputs something like '3.6, pg. 31', but I want it to output something like 'sec. 3.6, pg. 31'.

And so on.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436/184389) You should have a look at the [`cleveref`](https://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) package